# How to add plain PHP library into Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, 2checkout

I am using 2checkout API to integrate payments in my application. I am following their [API Tutorial](https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/payment-api/tutorial). I made slight modifications to their approach. Below is the unmodified front-end code by tutorial.

```
<form id="myCCForm" action="payment.php" method="post">
<input id="token" name="token" type="hidden" value="">
<div>
    <label>
        <span>Card Number</span>
    </label>
    <input id="ccNo" type="text" size="20" value="" autocomplete="off" required />
</div>
<div>
    <label>
        <span>Expiration Date (MM/YYYY)</span>
    </label>
    <input type="text" size="2" id="expMonth" required />
    <span> / </span>
    <input type="text" size="2" id="expYear" required />
</div>
<div>
    <label>
        <span>CVC</span>
    </label>
    <input id="cvv" size="4" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off" required />
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit Payment">
```

I changed  the line `<form id="myCCForm" action="payment.php" method="post">`to `<form id="myCCForm" action="{{route('postPayment)}}" method="post">` and also added CSRF token field in the above form.

This thing is working fine.

The 2nd Part is server side script that I want to handle in Laravel application. In tutorial this is written in payment.php. The script is working fine in payment.php but I am trying to write it in controller as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\TwoCheckout;



class PaymentsController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $twoCheckOut = TwoCheckout::find(1);
        return view('payment')->with('twoCheckOut',$twoCheckOut);
    }

    public function process()
    {
       require_once("2checkout-php/lib/Twocheckout.php");

        Twocheckout::privateKey('6CC34113-3588-4B09-8ECB-958C0B3299F3');
        Twocheckout::sellerId('901303383');
        Twocheckout::sandbox(true);


        try {
            $charge = Twocheckout_Charge::auth(array(
                "sellerId" => "901303383",
                "merchantOrderId" => "123",
                "token" => 'Y2U2OTdlZjMtOGQzMi00MDdkLWJjNGQtMGJhN2IyOTdlN2Ni',
                "currency" => 'USD',
                "total" => '10.00',
                "billingAddr" => array(
                    "name" => 'Testing Tester',
                    "addrLine1" => '123 Test St',
                    "city" => 'Columbus',
                    "state" => 'OH',
                    "zipCode" => '43123',
                    "country" => 'USA',
                    "email" => 'testingtester@2co.com',
                    "phoneNumber" => '555-555-5555'
                ),
                "shippingAddr" => array(
                    "name" => 'Testing Tester',
                    "addrLine1" => '123 Test St',
                    "city" => 'Columbus',
                    "state" => 'OH',
                    "zipCode" => '43123',
                    "country" => 'USA',
                    "email" => 'testingtester@2co.com',
                    "phoneNumber" => '555-555-5555'
                )
            ), 'array');
            if ($charge['response']['responseCode'] == 'APPROVED') {
                echo "Thanks for your Order!";
            }
        } catch (Twocheckout_Error $e) {
            $e->getMessage();
        }
    }


}
```

The problem is occurring in following lines.

```
require_once("2checkout-php/lib/Twocheckout.php");

            Twocheckout::privateKey('6CC34113-3588-4B09-8ECB-958C0B3299F3');
            Twocheckout::sellerId('901303383');
            Twocheckout::sandbox(true);
```

**ERROR**

> BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2099:
>   Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::privateKey()

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have a model named `Twocheckout` that you are importing at the top of your file with:

```
use App\TwoCheckout;
```

This means that all uses of `Twocheckout` in that controller file will refer to the Eloquent model, which in turn means you can't access the class with the same name coming from the [2checkout library](https://github.com/2Checkout/2checkout-php/blob/master/lib/Twocheckout.php). To fix that you can use an alias for the model class name like so:

```
use App\TwoCheckout as TwoCheckoutModel;
```

And where you need the model class just use that:

```
public function index()
{
    $twoCheckOut = TwoCheckoutModel::find(1);
    return view('payment')->with('twoCheckOut', $twoCheckOut);
}
```

That way the class name `Twocheckout` will refer to the correct library class.

Comment: changed the name of model from TwoCheckout to TwoCheckoutAccount... another error is for line `Twocheckout::privateKey('6CC34113-3588-4B09-8ECB-958C0B3299F3');`  *Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Twocheckout' not found*

Comment: That because it's resolving inside the controller namespace, which is `App\Http\Controllers`. You can add an additional `use Twocheckout;` statement to specify that the class should be resolved in the global namespace.